# running assembly on terminal mac

Tags: assembly, terminal

This code should work on linux, is there a way to make it run on terminal without modifying it?
This is for a class assignment where most students are using linux

## This is a simple "Hello World!" program

```
.section    .rodata #read only data section
str:    .string "Hello World!\n"
########
.text   #the beginnig of the code
.globl  main    #the label "main" is used to state the initial point of 
this program
.type   main, @function # the label "main" representing the beginning 
of a function
main:   # the main function:
pushq   %rbp        #save the old frame pointer
movq    %rsp,   %rbp    #create the new frame pointer

movq    $str,%rdi   #the string is the only paramter passed to the 
printf function (remember- first parameter goes in %rdi).
movq    $0,%rax
call    printf      #calling to printf AFTER we passed its parameters.

#return from printf:
movq    $0, %rax    #return value is zero (just like in c - we tell the 
OS that this program finished seccessfully)
movq    %rbp, %rsp  #restore the old stack pointer - release all used 
memory.
popq    %rbp        #restore old frame pointer (the caller function 
frame)
ret         #return to caller function (OS)
```

Comment: Mac OSX is not Linux though it is Unix but Linux is not Unix either.

Comment: I know, Im asking if theres a way to compile the program on mac without downloading linux

Comment: As long as you will use only calls from clib as in your example, this may be bendable enough to get somehow working mac binary, although I'm not sure if you can enforce the linux calling convention and find pre-compiled clib for that one. But if this is some assembly course, and later some system call will be introduced, you will have to rewrite that part of code every time with OSX equivalent. Just installing some VM linux box sounds like 0.5-3h one time investment and mitigating risk of future headache and N*3h figuring out whether you have bug in your core code, or in your mac conversion.

Comment: Also while both OSX and linux are well hardened OSes, you will be writing assembly. Having that inside some kind of sandbox like VM box sounds quite reassuring to me (still haunted by the 8/16 bit era, where usually every single bug in code resulted in hard reset of machine and several minutes of delay of loading the assembler, loading last saved version of source, and re-doing all the changes again since then + searching for the new bug). It's probably zero risk that you will truly damage anything by accident under OSX... still deleting full `~/.` sounds like non-zero probability.

Comment: Downloading Linux won't help you.  Install the Xcode Developer tools and use `as` or install nasm.

Comment: thank you all!, what do you mean by "as"?